# Which version of php add invocation of method returned by a function

Tags: php, function, version

In this code:

```
class Foo {
  private $foo;
  public function Foo($foo) {
    $this->foo = $foo;
  }
  public function getFoo() {
    return $this->foo;
  }
}

$a = new Foo(new Foo('bar'));

echo $a->getFoo()->getFoo();
```

In old php I'll coudn't call second `getFoo` I'll need to assign it to some variable. Which version of php added this feature?

Comment: FWIW, PHP 5.4 lets you do `echo (new Foo(new Foo('bar'))->getFoo()->getFoo();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In old php I'll coudn't call second getFoo I'll need to assign it to some variable. Which version of php added this feature?

Maybe in a *really* old PHP version. It wouldn't work in PHP 4, because returning `$this->foo` would return by value, and not by reference. Returning `&$this->foo` would work though. Since PHP 5.0 (if I recall correctly), objects are always returned by reference, so the code above should work without problems in PHP >= 5.